# With a Mac app that LSUIElement set, how can I optionally show the Dock icon?

Tags: macos

I'd like my Mac App which is a menubar-only app to optionally also show a Dock icon, so users can click the Dock icon to show the user interface of the app.

The reason for this is that it confuses new users when they launch the app for the first time—only a menubar icon shows up, and no Dock icon. Some users assume the app doesn't work or has crashed.

How can I still show the Dock icon even with LSUIElement=1 set?

Answer (score 2):

You can change the `activationPolicy` of the application object to make it a regular app (with a Dock icon and main menu), like so:

```
[NSApp setActivationPolicy:NSApplicationActivationPolicyRegular];
```

Since 10.9, you can also switch it back (without quitting and relaunching) to `NSApplicationActivationPolicyAccessory`.